# Why Router.go doesn't works on observe callback

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a template like this :

```
Template.playDetails.created = function () {
  /* Catch removed documents and redirect client if happens */
  Games.find({_id: gameId}).observe({
    removed: function () {
        console.log("Ooops game deleted !");
        Alerts("The game was deleted by owner", "danger");
        Router.go("playList"); 
    }
  });
};
```

And when i delete a game the log is shown on console but neither Alerts or Router.go works.

I tried to call Router.go with a time out but that didn't change anythings

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ Router.go('playList'); }, 10);
```

Is there anything i didn't do well ?

Comment: I forgot it in my post, but of course i get the gameId, and the observe callback works cause i see the log in console.

Comment: You can edit your post with the small "edit" button if you need to add information.

Comment: You have a typo: `alert("The game was deleted by owner");` `alert()` only takes one argument - you have two. Also, we need to see your `router.js` file. It's possible `Router.go` isn't working because there's no route named `playList`.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny I assumed it was not the default `alert` since it's `Alerts`...

Comment: Hi, thanks for tour time, as kyll said this is not thé defaut alert, and i have a route named playList (i use it on my navbar and i checked the name, this is correct :-/